# How much larger is Sage Centipede than Elder Centipede?

Tags: one-punch-man

In Chapter 158 of the manga *One Punch Man*, it's mentioned that the number of limbs Sage Centipede has is 6666 in total. I was wondering whether the number of Elder Centipede's limbs was ever mentioned, to compare their sizes.

How much larger is Sage Centipede than Elder Centipede?